# Tubular neighbourhoods are unique up to ambient isotopy?

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, kirby-calculus

Let $M$ be a closed smooth submanifold of $N$. It is well known that tubular neigbourhoods of $M$ are diffeomorphic to the normal bundle of $M$ in $N$ and therefore to each other. Are they smoothly isotopic? I think I know how to prove that they are, but having a reference would be nice.

If they are not, how is it enough to just assign a framing to a knot to obtain a surgery? Is the pair (framing, sphere embedding) enough for high dimensional handle attachments/surgery?

Definition: for a Riemannian metric $g$ on $N$, let $\nu_{g,\epsilon}(M)$ be the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $M$ in $N$. For $\epsilon$ small enough, $\nu_{g,\epsilon}(M)$ is a tubular neighbourhood.

Comment: Tubular neighborhoods are unique up to isotopy. Search for "tubular neighborhod" in the index of M. Hirsch's "Differential topology".

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Thank you! This reference additionally obtains a bundle map at the end of the isotopy.

Comment: I forgot to add that the isotopy can be made ambient by the isotopy extension lemma (chapter 8 of Hirsch's text).

Comment: I think the best treatment of tubular neighborhoods is given in Wall's recent book on differential topology, in particular he gives an intrinsic definition of a tubular neighborhood (linear disk bundle) instead of the very awkward definition via Riemannian metric. See Theorem 2.5.5 of Wall.

Comment: @StefanFriedl Thank you, that does seem like a nice textbook. It's the same definition as in Hirsch. Wall, though, also shows that this definition is equivalent to the Riemannian one.

Comment: Tubular neighborhoods are unique up to isotopy, but different framings of the tubular neighborhood of the knot give different 2-handle attachments. The post asks about this too, so I just wanted to say I would love a reference for that as well.

Comment: @StefanFriedl: Wall's proof of the existence of tubular neighborhoods doesn't work for me. His Theorem 2.3.2 p. 45 uses Corollary A.2.6, which seems incorrect since it doesn't require $X$ closed, and he proves A.2.6 using A.2.5, which assumes $X$ compact. I am not sure that A.2.5 works for closed noncompact $X$, and I think A.2.6 fails for nonclosed $X$.